# JBoss Tools 4.16.0 Final completely freeze Eclipse 4.16 (2020-06)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, windows-10, jboss-tools, eclipse-2020-06

I'm using `Eclipse EE 4.16` (2020-06) - on Windows 10 Professional x64 - and I've tried to install the `JBoss Tools 4.16.0 Final` Plugin for it.

It literally break the IDE, whatever I try to do the IDE freezes: If I copy -> paste some code the IDE freezes for about 10 seconds (the screen become gray and Eclipse not responding).. the same thing happens if I try to navigate through classes or method (even worst..).

I tries even with `Eclipse EE 4.15` (2020-03) but I obtain the same result.

Googling around I have found hypothetical solutions regarding `eclipse.ini` file changes but nothing works.

I attach a thread dump [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aK1h-27rOFIkKcq3x3DKm5ZUWIqSzr05/view?usp=sharing).

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

can you please also try https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/jbosstools/2020-09/4.17.0.Final.html? Its based on Eclipse 2020-09, so it could help.
Which JDK version are you using?

Thanks for response!
Josef

FYI: you can also report issues related Jboss Tools in JIRA: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBIDE